# Xpath or css selector attrbute value in scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy, css-selectors

Hi there I am new to scrapy and I want to extract an attribute value form an html element. So what could be the right way to extract that attribute value form that html . I want to extract "data-next-url" attribute

```
<div class="loading_more_jobs" data-type="loading_more_jobs" style="display:none;" data-next-url="https://www.ziprecruiter.com/candidate/search?search=restaurant&amp;page=2&amp;location=Atlanta%2C+Georgia"></div>
```

I am using that xpath but it is not working

```
 response.xpath('//*[@class="loading_more_jobs"]/@data-next-url').extract()
```

Comment: Disable the JS in your browser, and then see if that element is present in source code, I am sure its not there, your Xpath looks alright

Comment: so what would I do if I want to get that attribute value

Comment: If its not in source code, you have to study that website how it loads that data, via AJAX or they already have that on page in form of JSON or whatever.

Comment: https://www.ziprecruiter.com/candidate/search?search=restaurant&location=Atlanta%2C+Georgia  

I want to get that info from "load more jobs " there from that page

Answer (score 0):

If you check source HTML you'll find this:

```
  <button class="load_more_jobs" data-type="load_more_jobs" data-next-url="">Load More Job Results</button>
  <div class="loading_more_jobs" data-type="loading_more_jobs" style="display:none;"></div>
```

But you can get next page URL anyway:

```
<div class="job_results" data-this-url="/candidate/search?search=restaurant&amp;location=Atlanta%2C+Georgia" data-next-url="/candidate/search?location=Atlanta%2C+Georgia&amp;page=2&amp;search=restaurant" data-type="job_results">
```

=>

```
response.xpath('//div[@class="job_results"]/@data-next-url').extract_first()
```

or

```
<link rel="next" href="https://www.ziprecruiter.com/candidate/search?location=Atlanta%2C+Georgia&amp;page=2&amp;search=restaurant">
```

=>

```
response.xpath('//link[@rel="next"]/@href').extract_first()
```